# How to use C# XNA timer?

Tags: c#-4.0, xna-4.0

I am using XNA my rocket is creating smoke objects when it fly. I need to know how to use some timer in XNA for these simple smoke objects. When the object is create ...wait 2 seconds and destroy this object. Can somebody help pls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your update method should be being passed a GameTime object. Record the time in ctor or setup method, and compare it every update. Once a specified period has elapsed, run your teardown method.

Comment: can u show me some code for this pls? i am begginer in XNA and dont know how to write the code to get the time and check the time....

Comment: Your game objects should be inheriting from GameObject (or something similar, I don't have xna installed on this machine) and will have a Update(GameTime) method. If your game objects are being updated your self in your main program Update method, pass the gametime object along so that the objects will be able to read its state each update, and make decisions like this one.